# MarkLogic 8 - Node.js Client API - Can I do a SPARQL Query?

Tags: node.js, sparql, marklogic

As the title says, I want to know if I can do a SPARQL query in the node.js client API or if I need to use the Server Side Javascript API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MarkLogic node.js client API can evaluate SPARQL queries. See the jsdoc here: http://docs.marklogic.com/jsdoc/graphs.html#sparql

**Update**: here's a full example:

```
var marklogic = require('marklogic')
var config = { /* ... */ }
var db = marklogic.createDatabaseClient(config)

db.graphs.sparql(
  'application/sparql-results+json',
  'select ?s ?p ?o\n' +
  'where { ?s ?p ?o }\n' +
  'limit 10'
)
.result()
.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.head)
  console.log(response.results)
})
.catch(console.log.bind(console))
```

Note that the results format (the first argument to `db.graphs.sparql()`) must be a known semantic format, as described [here](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/semantics/semantic-searches#id_83694).

Comment: Okay that answers my question, I can't seem to find an example of how this is used...

Comment: Is it like this:

    var graphs = require('graphs');
    
    var query = graphs.sparql('json', undefined, undefined, 'SOME SPARQL QUERY');
    var success = function() { };
    var fail = function() { };
    
    query(success, fail);